Define preprocessors for dependency projects
I am using visual studio 2019.
I have a project A (dll) depending on a project B (static library).
So when building A, it builds indeed B first.
So I would like to have a preprocessor defined when building B only when built by A.
Note that I also have other projects that also use project B, but I don't want to define that preprocessor in these cases. So I can't simply define that preprocessor on project B configuration.
Also, projects A and B doesn't have any common source files.
Looks like preprocessor definitions can't be inherited.
How to do it ?

Just a thought: If your only main issue is the build order for a particular SLN, did you try setting it manually in `Project\Project Build Order..."?
